# An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm a student and currently trying to start a project. I tried shifting to different ide and also tried re downloading dependencies but it is giving save whitelabel error page. I followed the tutorial well but dont understand if something is wrong with code or with the compilation of thymeleaf please help...

error message

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html

org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "~{base::Layout(~{::section)}" (template: "home" - line 2, col 53)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "~{base::Layout(~{::section)}" (template: "home" - line 2, col 53)
```

base.html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th= "http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment= "layout(content)">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>base html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div th:replace="${content}"></div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

home

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="base::Layout(~{::section)">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>this is home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 >this is home page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
package com.Hospital.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is your home.html file located under src\main\resources\templates folder. Also remove all the content inside the home.html and put some simple text and try

Answer (score 0):

Change capital L to small l in home.html 2nd line.
layout spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in home.html:

```
th:replace="base::layout(~{::section})"
```